# Error after enabling flat categories and products

Tags: category, flat

I enabled flat categories and products and then re-indexed the data. I also cleared the cache but I am still getting this error on the product page. Everything works perfect when the FLAT option is disabled. I need the flat option enabled to help my store perform faster.... any suggestions?

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.seller_id' in    'where clause'

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):      Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT count(DI...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT count(DI...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1036): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `seller_id` is your product attribute you will need to enable `visible_on_front` and `used_in_product_listing` options for that attribute.

`visible_on_front` will 
add your attribute to product flat table and `used_in_product_listing` will be used by category flat tables.

Answer (score 0):

If `seller_id` is the product attribute, then the issue might be upon re-indexation the attribute and its value are not getting saved in the flat tables.
Only the attributes that are marked to be used in product listing are copied to the flat tables. Mark "seller_id" to be used in product listing and re-index everything.